# C# Write Json file error

Tags: c#, json

I want to write data from Object to Json file.

My class Person

```
public class Person
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private int height;
    private double weight;

    public Person() { }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int height, double weight)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

My Program class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
        Person ps1 = new Person("Tay", "Son", 180, 99.99);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ps1,Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\person.json", json);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

person.json only displays: "{}"

Please helps me to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
public string firstName;
public string lastName;
public int height;
public double weight;
```

Private fields aren't serialised.

Answer (score 1):

Change private to public in the class member declarations.

Turn the members into properties by adding `get` and `set` methods

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstName { get; set; };
    public string lastName { get; set; };
    public int height { get; set; };
    public double weight { get; set; };

    public Person() { }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int height, double weight)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
// serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
            Person ps1 = new Person("Tay", "Son", 180, 99.99);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ps1);
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\person.json", json);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Class:

```
public class Person
{
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public double weight { get; set; }

        public Person() { }
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int height, double weight)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.height = height;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
}
```